# Как я могу сгенерирвать массив из функций с разными параметрами и этот массив передать в Promise.allSettled?

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть функция:

```
const sayHi = async (name) => ...
```

Есть массив с именами

```
['Bob', 'Mike']
```

Как я могу динамически создать клоны функций `sayHi` и поместить в  `Promise.allSettled([]`
В результате получить что то подобие:

```
 Promise.allSettled([sayHi('Bob'), sayHi('Mike')];
```

Это возможно?

Comment: Крайне рекомендую вам ознакомится с такими методами (для функций) как: `call`, `bind` и `apply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо передать массив функций.
Для этого необходимо, допустим методом map пройтись по массиву и сформировать массив функций и уже его передавать в Promise.allSettled

```js
const sayHi = async (name) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`hi ${name}`);
            resolve(`name = ${name}`);
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    })
}
    
const arr = ['Bob', 'Mike', 'Вася', 'Маша'];

Promise.allSettled(arr.map(item => sayHi(item)))
.then(res => {
    console.log('returned', res);
})
```

Answer (score -2):

В общем с помощью цикла перебрал массив сгенерировал строку вида '[..,..]' и через eval выполнил код.

```
Promise.allSettled(eval(runCode))
```

Comment: `eval` - не лучшая практика, часто он заблокирован на сайтах, из-за CSP (Content Security Policy - Политика Защиты Контента), так что ответ не слишком пригоден. К тому же из-за него появляются бреши в безопасности.

Comment: но зачем генерировать строку, если в соседнем ответе используется специальный метод, который на основе одно массива получает другой?

Comment: @Grundy да, тот отвел был дан позже я только сейчас увидел